# Find an example of product of operators not Jointly Continuous in strong topology.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

I'm trying to find an example of the fact that the product of operators is not jointly continuous in the strong topology.

I know the example of the unilateral shift (that is on wikipedia), but I would like to find ANOTHER example not concerning the shift operator and I'm unable to find it.

Can you give me a hand please?

Comment: See problems 111 and 28 of Halmos 'A Hilbert Space Problem Book'. Note that $B(H)$ with strong operator topology is not first-countable so one has to consider all possible nets (not just sequences) to prove that a mapping is continuous.